# Deploy from Visual Studio to HoloLens Emulator without restarting the emulator?

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

Waiting for the HoloLens Emulator's OS to boot up every time I make some changes to my app and I recompile can be annoying. Is there a way to deploy a new build to an already running emulator?

Comment: I do this every time. Most often the emulator hangs at the start so that I need to deploy twice. I am working with Unity and .NET as scripting backend. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just don't shut down the emulator.  You can push the Stop button in Visual Studio, make your changes in Unity and rebuild.  Your open project should detect the changes and ask you to reload the project. Hit the Play button in VS and your new code is redeployed to the emulator.